Center absolute text under image
I have a row of four images displayed next to each other, and I want to show text beneath each image when hovered over. The text should remain hidden until hover and should not affect the content's width. However, when I position the text absolutely, I struggle to center it properly under each image. Any idea how to solve it?
Snippet of my current structure:
<div class"items">
 <div class="item-single">
  <a href="">
   <img src="">
  </a>
  <p>Long text under image</p>
 </div>
</div>

If I set item-single to position:absolute;, I cannot center text properly under each respective image. Setting item-single to position:relative; makes the text fit inside the div, which can cause unwanted multi-line text.

I added the following to the p element, and it seems to do the job. The p element is absolute, while its parent is relative.


    text-wrap: nowrap;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,0);




Generally, text-wrap: nowrap is used with text-overflow: ellipsis and overflow: hidden



.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: flex;}
<div class="dropdown" >
<a href="">
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" alt="Nature">
  </a>
  <p class="dropdown-content">Long text under image</p>
</div>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You need to understand how the position relative and absolute work together.
By adding margin: auto; along with position absolute should solve your problem.
This should help.


.item-single {
  position: relative;
  
  height: 201px;
  width: 201px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.item-single a:hover ~ p {
  display: block;
}

.item-single p {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  
  display: none;
}
<div class"items">

  <div class="item-single">
    <a href="https://placehold.co/200">
     <img src="https://placehold.co/200" />
    </a>
    <p>Long text under image</p>
  </div>
  
  
</div>




If I set width of .item-single, I'll have a white space between images unless they match the coded width. That's not desired behavior.
Also, If I make the text in p element longer, it will create a multiline text instead of going outside the div.
